# XSLT: From XML to XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I dont have much XSLT experience and have come across some XSLT work.

I've got an input xml e.g:-

```
<Element1>
    <Data>
        <Header a1="REF" a2="2014-06-09"></Header>
        <Detail_1 b1="X" b2="Y">
            <Detail_2 c1="9" c2="10"></Detail_2>
        </Detail_1>
        <Detail_1 b1="Z" b2="A">
            <Detail_2 c1="11" c2="12"></Detail_2>
        </Detail_1>
    </Data>
</Element1>
```

I want to transform this into the following where I am trying to create a record i.e. Header.a2 + Detail_1 + Detail_2 :-

```
<n1:MyObject>
    <a2>2014-06-09</a2>
    <b1>X</b1>
    <b2>Y</b2>
    <c1>9</c1>
    <c2>10</c2>
</n1:MyObject>
<n1:MyObject>
    <a2>2014-06-09</a2>
    <b1>Z</b1>
    <b2>A</b2>
    <c1>11</c1>
    <c2>12</c2>
</n1:MyObject>
```

Can anyone please shed any light on how one would go about doing the transformation?

Thanks.

Comment: The output is not well-formed XML as it has two root elements.  You would need to enclose it in, for example, `<n1:MyObjects>...</n1:MyObjects>` to be well-formed.

Comment: ... and ensure you have properly declared the `n1:` namespace prefix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<xsl:template match="Detail_1">
  <n1:MyObject>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="preceding-sibling::Header/@a2" mode="toElem" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant-or-self::*/@*" mode="toElem" />
  </n1:MyObject>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*" mode="toElem">
  <xsl:element name="{name()}">
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. it also directed me to learn other options to traverse the tree.

Comment: @Bilal That was the intention! :)